# Nested Sets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, set

I created a procedural implementation of the nested set model in JavaScript.
The use case for this small library was that the front-end(presented as an MVC) needs to traverse hierarchical data from back-ends.

The library that I created satisfies the following:

- DSL-like architecture, with clear distinction between a tree and a node.
- Searching through the set for a node matching a given partial of it
- Retrieve parents for any given node
- Retrieve children for any given node
- Retrieve descendants for any particular node
- Utility methods determining "what" a node is, given it's coordinates
- A lesser distinguished way of finding siblings (parents[0] -> children = siblings)

The library is divided into two classes.

`NestedSetModel` is the base class and acts as a starting point for traversing the tree.

It's first function is to order the set by left values ascendantly. This is done for the presumption that descendants are always at a higher index(of the set) than parents.
The second function is to create an index of all right values.

```
var NestedSetModel = function(model) {
    this.model = [];
    this.index = {};

    // sort the set for deterministic order
    model.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        return a.left - b.left;
    });

    var self = this;

    // create an index
    for(var index in model) {
        if (!model.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
            continue;
        }

        this.index[model[index].right] = index;
    }

    for(var entry in model) {
        if (!model.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            var node = new NestedSetModelNode(model[entry], model, this.index);
            this.model.push(node);
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    return this;
}

NestedSetModel.prototype.compareNodes = function(a, b, strict) {
    var strict = strict || false;

    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    }

    var keys = [
        Object.keys(a),
        Object.keys(b)
    ];

    if (strict && keys[0].length !== keys[1].length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= keys[1].length; i++) {
        var prop = keys[1][i];


        if (a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!strict) {
        return true;
    }

    for (var prop in keys[0]) {
        if (b[prop] !== undefined && a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
            return false;
        }

        if (typeof a[prop] === 'object'
            && this.compareNodes(a[prop], b[prop], true) === false) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

NestedSetModel.prototype.find = function(partial, strict) {
    for (var key in this.model) {
        if (!this.model.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        } else if (this.compareNodes(this.model[key], partial, strict)) {
            return new NestedSetModelNode(this.model[key], this.model, this.index);
        }
    }
}
```

The second and final class is `NestedSetModelNode`. It contains methods related to relationships between nodes. I've omitted methods that perform rudementy calculations.

```
var NestedSetModelNode = function(node, model, index) {
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(node).forEach(function(prop) {
        self[prop] = node[prop];
    });

    this.model = model;
    this.index = index;
}

NestedSetModelNode.prototype.parents = function() {
    var parents = [];
    var self = this;

    this.model.map(function(node) {
        if (self.left > node.left && self.right < node.right) {
            parents.push(new NestedSetModelNode(node, self.model, self.index));
        }
    });

    return parents;
}

NestedSetModelNode.prototype.descendants = function() {
    var descendants = [];
    var num_items = Math.floor((this.right - this.left) / 2);

    for(var right in this.index) {
        if (right < this.right && right > this.left) {
            var node = this.model[this.index[right]];
            descendants.push(new NestedSetModelNode(node, this.model, this.index));
        }
    }

    return descendants;
}

NestedSetModelNode.prototype.children = function() {
    var children = [];
    var right = this.right - 1;

    while(true) {
        if (right === this.left) {
            break;
        }

        var child = this.model[this.index[right]];

        children.push(new NestedSetModelNode(child, this.model, this.index));
        right = child.left - 1;
    }

    return children.reverse();
}
```

Semantics aside, what improvements can I implement that will make this library more consistent and practical(performance wise) to compute client-side?

So far, I have created an index tree of right values for optimization of `r - l > 1` lookups.
This increases performance, as only half the amount of objects are actually traversed and compared.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting code,

the first thing that comes to mind is that `forEach`and `map` are slower than `for` loops, so you might want to consider converting those statements to `for` loops.

the second thing is that I assume you query several times these data structures, if that is the case then the node should know who is/are the parents and who is/are the children, it does not make sense to traverse (partially) the model every time to figure that out.

Other than that

- This

  ```
  // create an index
  for(var index in model) {
      if (!model.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          continue;
      }

      this.index[model[index].right] = index;
  }
  ```

  could be

  ```
  // create an index
  for(var index in model) {
      if (model.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          this.index[model[index].right] = index;
      }
  }
  ```

  by avoiding the `continue` statement
- This

  ```
  try {
      var node = new NestedSetModelNode(model[entry], model, this.index);
      this.model.push(node);
  } catch(e) {}
  ```

  intrigues me, I don't see what could go wrong with this code that you need a `try/catch`, even more intriguing is that you fail silently here, potentially providing wrong query results later in the game
- This part could be faster for strict comparisons:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i <= keys[1].length; i++) {
      var prop = keys[1][i];
       if (a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  if (!strict) {
      return true;
  }

  for (var prop in keys[0]) {
      if (b[prop] !== undefined && a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
          return false;
      }

      if (typeof a[prop] === 'object'
          && this.compareNodes(a[prop], b[prop], true) === false) {
          return false
      }
  }
  ```

  What you do here every time you check for strict comparison is comparing `b` with `a` using `!=`  and then again comparing `a` with `b` using `!==`. Since you know for strict comparison that the key count is the same, this is overkill. Furthermore I have doubts on `(b[prop] !== undefined && a[prop] !== b[prop])` if the value of `b[prop]` is `undefined` and the value of a[prop] is not `undefined`, then the comparison should be false. Furthermore I am not sure why you `this.compareNodes` in case of an object, if `a[prop] === b[prop]`, then the nodes cannot be different because it is the same object (as I understand it), if you want to really compare two different objects for the same properties, then that should should be before the `!==` check.

  I would counter propose something like this:

  ```
  if (!strict) {
    for (var prop in keys[1]) { //I still wonder, why 1, not 0?
      if (b[prop] != a[prop]) {
        return false;
      }
    }          
  } else {
    for (var prop in keys[0]) {
      if (typeof a[prop] == 'object') {
        if( !this.compareNodes(a[prop], b[prop], true)) {
          return false;
        }
      } else if (a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  //We made it thru, a and b are equal (enough)
  return true;
  ```
- Perhaps consider renaming `NestedSetModel.prototype.find` to `findFirst`, since it only returns the first match
- This

  ```
  var self = this;
  Object.keys(node).forEach(function(prop) {
      self[prop] = node[prop];
  });
  ```

  only needs `self` because of the forEach, from a style/performance perspective you could avoid this by going to a faster `for` loop.
- This

  ```
  this.model.map(function(node) {
       if (self.left > node.left && self.right < node.right) {
           parents.push(new NestedSetModelNode(node, self.model, self.index));
       }
   });
  ```

  utilizes `map` which builds an array for you, if you are not going to use the results of `map`, then you should use `forEach`, and since you are interested in speed, you should use a simple `for` loop.
- On the whole I dont get your data structur with `left` and `right`, I would have loved to see a small example with data
- I also don't get the difference between `children` and `descendants` unless you mean `descendants` also include grandchildren etc. I think you could find a better name than `descendants`.
- An excellent point of @Megawac, which I completely missed is that using `for .. in` is [considered very bad practice for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript). If you simply use the regular `for` loop then that will be faster because you no longer need check `hasOwnProperty` every single time.

Comment: no mention of `for .. in` on arrays all over the place?

Comment: With so much advice leaning towards performance (which was sought), store the length of arrays before traversing them in traditional `for` loops. However, I'd start with the more readable `forEach` et al and switch only after profiling reveals a problem.